# Typescript Array Map Return Object

Tags: typescript

I have the following code.

```
array.map(val => { return {
  key1: val.key1,
  key2: val.key2
}});
```

Is there any way to reduce the code to something like this?

```
array.map(val => {
  key1: val.key1,
  key2: val.key2
});
```

Answer (score 193, accepted):

If you put it in parenthesis the compiler will treat it as an object literal not a code block:

```
array.map(val => ({
  key1: val.key1,
  key2: val.key2
}));
```

A type assertion also works if you have an interface for the object literal (but is not as type safe):

```
interface IKeys { key1: string; key2: string }
array.map(val => <IKeys>{
  key1: val.key1,
  key2: val.key2
});
```

Comment: If using React JSX compiler, be aware of using <IKeys> style type assertions as it is ambiguous with JSX grammar and thus you must use {...} as IKeys casting syntax.

Comment: @guru_florida Can you explain more? And how would it work for Typescript?

Comment: @CyberMew after the `=>` an `{` is always interpreted as a code block, no exceptions. But after `=>` we can have any expression, including a parenthesis expression `(...)` and inside this new expression we can have an object literal, but the `(...)` does not in any other way change the meaning of the object expression. The type assertion `<IKey>` serves a similar function, it will introduce a new type of expression after the `=>` instead of having the `{` which always means code block. Hope this makes it a bit more clear

Answer (score 35):

As an update to @Titian Cernicova-Dragomir's answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755280/624597), it's worth mentioning the [`as` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-as-operator) (for Type Assertion), especially useful when working with React's TSX(JSX) files, equivalent to the `<Type>` syntax:

```
interface IKeys { key1: string; key2: string }
// notice the parentheses, to avoid confusion with a block scope
array.map(val => ({
    key1: val.key1,
    key2: val.key2
} as IKeys));
```

It was introduced because the angle brackets syntax (`<ComponentOrElement>`) is reserved for components / JSX Elements.

Comment: This isn't completely type-safe - you will get compile errors if key1/key2 are missing or incorrectly typed, but if you add an additional param key3 you won't get an error.

Comment: @Jonathan  In a way isn't, but on the other hand, it is like telling TS: "from now on, treat this unknown 'thing' as this particular type" - so it's not a strict contract like in the case of `interface`. As long as you don't try to use `key3`, it will be type-safe. I would argue that `key3` would be a bit like some unknown prototype. property.

Answer (score 17):

None of the above options have worked for me with React's TSX files.

This is the code that worked for me:

```
interface IKeys { key1: string; key2: string }

array.map((val: any): IKeys => ({
    key1: val.key1,
    key2: val.key2
}));
```

Comment: This is the only solution that's completely type-safe, unlike `as IKeys`

Answer (score 1):

You can use as well

```
interface IKeys { key1: string; key2: string }

array.map<IKeys>(val => {
    key1: val.key1,
    key2: val.key2
});
```