# How to replace values in a d3.csv-parsed object using forEach (Angular/TypeScript)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, d3.js

I am trying to implement a [d3-example](https://vizhub.com/curran/900cb204023748b9a8bdf2273bdefe03?edit=files&file=index.js) in Angular I am facing a problem when trying to replace values in the data object. (I use Angular v12.0.4 and d3 v7.0.0 according to package.json)

Here is my data.csv:

```
year,population
1950,2525149312
1951,2571867515
1952,2617940399
1953,2664029010
```

And here the function for replacing the strings with Number and Date-objects:

```js
let data = d3.csv('/assets/data.csv').then(data => {

  data.forEach(d => {
    d.population = +d.population;
    d.year = new Date(d.year);
  })
})
```

When implementing the same code in a standalone .js file, there is no problem, but in Angular, I get the error

`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)` for `d.population = ...` and

`Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)` for `d.year = ...`

I have another question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68034611/problem-implementing-stacked-bar-chart-using-d3-stack-in-angular-v11-12) that might or might not be related since examples that should work don't, when implemented in Angular.

Is there something I need to consider when implementing this in Angular?

Edit:

Tried with parentheses (and also with an interface) as suggested:

```js
    let data2 = await d3.csv('/assets/world-population-by-year-2015.csv').then(data1 => {

      
      data1.forEach(d => ({
        population: +d.population,    // also tried `as unknown as Number` istead of +
        year: new Date(d.year)
      }))
      console.log(data1)              // 0: {year: "1950", population: "2525149312"} ...
      return data1
      
    })
    console.log(data2[0]['year'])         // 1950
    console.log(typeof(data2[0]['year'])) // string
```

The type-error dissapeared but it seems nothing gets changed, the values are still strings. The result is the same with an interface instead of parenthesis:

```js
interface IPopulation {
  population: Number;
  year: Date;
}

.then(data1 => <IPopulation>{...
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use an interface like it's show here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47755280/765395

Comment: @RobinMackenzie The error disappeared but the strings are not changed to Number or Date respectively, see my edit. It almost seems the forEach function doesn't iterate over the array at all.

Comment: Iterating with console.log(d) inside forEach works as expected